# Implicit rules for CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying add some implicit rules in CMake that will generate direct dependencies (like .c files from Bison .y files). How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use custom commands in CMake to do this.  There is a wiki article here:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_generate_a_source_file_during_the_build.3F

Also, you might want to try the tutorial mentioned in my blog here:

http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/7

(See step 5: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html#s5)

-Bill

Comment: examples, examples, examples. Both wiki and documentation are painfully short of solid examples for these not so edge cases.